# Вопрос по Python + BeautifulSoup. Достает другую ссылку

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

**Вот код :**

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


def get_html(url):
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers = {'User-Agent': 
               'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'}
    r = session.get(url)
    if r.ok:
        print('Запрос выполнен успешно')
        return r.text
    else:
        print('Запрос не выполнен \n', r.status_code)


def content():
    name = input('Какое аниме вы бы хотели посмотреть?').lower().strip()

    if name == 'магическая битва':
        magic_battle()
    elif name == 'наруто':
        naruto()
    else:
        print('Введите правильное название аниме')


def magic_battle():
    episode = input('Введите эпизод')
    url = f'https://jut.su/jujutsu-kaisen/episode-{episode}.html'
    html = get_html(url)

    soup = BS(html, 'lxml')
    video = soup.find('source', label='720p').get('src')
    print(video)

    
content()
```

Все работает, с сайта достает ссылку, но переходя по ссылке выходит ошибка **403 Forbidden**
Получается JavaScript меняет ссылку или как? Потому что в коде страницы когда копирую ссылку,все работает.Что делать? Использовать selenium или можно без него?

Comment: что такое magic_battle() и naruto()? таких функций нев в вашем коде

Comment: что должен делать ваш скрипт?

Comment: @Jack_oS magic_battle() есть, до функции naruto() не дошел еще.Скрипт достает ссылку на видео определенного аниме и определенной серии. Но эта ссылка выдает ошибку(403).Хотя ссылка должна парсится правильная,значит JS меняет как то ссылку?

Comment: ссылка и так парсится правильная... что вы ходите с ней делать? скачать .mp4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас hash в пределаx сессии, а она локальная.
Вынесите ее наружу и добавьте код для скачивания файла.
Только этой же сессией качайте.